# Add UIView to another UIView as a SubView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I have a UIView, and I want to add an another UIView as a subView to it.

This is what I have done:

```
- (IBAction)showVerification:(id)sender {
    [self.viewM addSubview: self.verificationView];
    [self.labelVerification setText:offerId];
}
```

And this is the result:

[image]

Can You help me? Is it impossible to add a UIView to another in .xib file?

Comment: I think you'll have to be a bit more specific about what you want to happen.  Also, can you explain what is wrong with the result you are getting.

Comment: what is the result you wold like to have?

Comment: I'll add the image at the end of my question.

Comment: @Fogmeister, it should not fill all the screen. Just look at my first image. I selected the UIView in the right side. It should be fit for that size.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it programmatically :

```
UIView* view2 = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(30, 100, 1024-30, 768-110)];
[self.view addSubView:view2];
```

Comment: What is the problem to add it in .xib file? Is it impossible? and why?

Comment: i think programmatically is easier

Comment: just he constains or autolaout make this result you have to remove those constrains form uiview and all will be settled :)

Answer (score 1):

See my images i have done same and nothing is moved in it

Two views

[image: Image 1]

After combining them just drag and drop it in side the view

[image: Image 2]

And in Simulator

[image: Image 3]

Comment: Take a look at the right photo again. Can you see the background image on it. how can I set that Image? Ofcourse I have UIView and then I add an ImageView to it, and then I add the final UIView, as shown in my right picture.

Comment: And now I want to add the new UIView to the final UIView.

Comment: I appreciate for your complete answer. +1 until now.

Comment: And the point is, I don't want to drag and drop it. It is not as easy as that, As you see my code, I want to do that programmatically via `AddSubView`.

Comment: you can also do this by coding as @Jossef has instructed just create the view with desired property and size and add it to view :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do as Wolvorin suggested or set an `outlet` for that leftview then add it into view on button event